# How does the defer keyword work with use-package?

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to figure out how "defer" works. Let's say I have two color schemes:

```
(use-package gruvbox-theme
  :config
  (load-theme 'gruvbox-dark-medium t))

(use-package solarized-theme)
```

The first one (gruvbox) is the default one and the one I use.
I don't use the "solarized" theme but I would like to have it just in case I change my mind one day.
In my situation does it make sense to defer the solarized package like so?

```
(use-package solarized-theme
  :defer t)
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, **yes**.

**Slightly longer version**

Defer; lets you defer loading of the provided package, either by saying `t` which will make the package not load until you use it or by giving `:defer` an integer of number of seconds to defer the loading.
In most situations I would suggest that you employ the use of the `:commands` keyword. It will defer loading of the package, but can at the same time expose commands that will make the package load.